# Control computer on same network

Tags: command-line, remote-access

I would like to know if it's possible to control a computer on the same network without installing any software on the other computer and from the command line if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Question is not clear, if you need to restart or shutdown a remote computer see this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try remote desktop connection.
May be this video might help.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke_t5-N-SEY

If not you will definately find lot of resources how to connect the other computer from remote desktop connection in local network.

Comment: does it work without installing software on computer B (the one i want to control)?

Comment: Generally remote desktop is default installed in all windows computer